# Ontario debt is high, what does this mean for our future?

Tags: ontario

I keep hearing how Ontario is in a lot of debt. (around 350 BN in 2018).

Can anyone explain the impact of this increasing debt for Ontario and Canada?
Can we just keep taking on more debt to finance our province/country?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about government finance, which is specifically off-topic. Please see https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It's a legitimate question chris!

Comment: @Jonathan The question is not legitimate on *this* site, because this website is about **personal** finance and money, not **government** finance and money. But it could be a legitimate question on https://economics.stackexchange.com/ or https://politics.stackexchange.com. When this question gets closed, you might want to delete it and repost it there. Or you could ask a moderator to migrate it by flagging your own question for moderator attention.

Comment: @DJ "the Ontario **Liberal** government stopped spending anything at all over a year ago?"  Because the Liberals were voted out of office, or because the government shut down?

Comment: @Philipp I answered and also voted to reopen, It is extremely easy and always an option to merely modify the original question to add a personal finance slant to it. "I'm looking to buy municipal bonds". And there are non-subjective answers possible to the question even though the issuer is a sovereign political institution. Voting to close is just lazy.

you or anyone else, vote to reopen if you feel the same way.

Comment: @Jonathan I voted to re-open, but need more votes to get it open

Comment: @RonJohn Because the Liberals were voted out of office. Any excessive increase in the Ontario debt is now entirely the responsibility of the Conservative Party of Ontario.

Comment: @DJClayworth "Because the Liberals were voted out of office."  OK, but I don't see how it's relevant to the question.

Comment: @Jonathan We have a site on [economics.se], where this question would be perfectly acceptable. I suggest asking there.

Comment: @RonJohn The original question started "I keep hearing how the Liberals keep spending...". Probably not needed any more.

Comment: Yes guys i took out the liberals part, I want to be fair and promote equality!

Answer (score -1):

Debt is primarily used by sovereign institutions to fund infrastructure projects like roads, schools, and general operations. Select groups of people - typically residents and corporations - pay taxes on the interest to that debt.

The debt itself is usually in the form of bonds, which domestic and foreign investors look at and decide if they want to buy. If the investors don't think they will get paid back, then they will not buy new debt.

This begins to severely impacts a sovereign institution's ability to finance itself, because they have overextended, so this is where limitations in how much debt is possible become apparent.

A sovereign dependent area of a bigger country typically does not have the option to keep taking on more debt, like the bigger country can, but they can default on prior debt, and just start taking on new debt again. This is usually a last resort though, and holding debt before any meaningful consequences can continue for a long long time.

Comment: "they can default on prior debt, and just start taking on new debt again".  If they default, then there is a high risk that they will do it again, so investors won't buy the debt (or will only do so in exchange for punitive interest rates).

Comment: @MartinBonner its a possibility, but a more likely possibility supported by history is that it will just be different investors buying.